# Alternative ways since Windows Form Application.Exit() does not close UI threads immediately?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've this part of my personal code where I wanted to improve, in summary the general structure of the program is like this:

```
// This form is just an UI onscreen label that I want to display.
var task = Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
// Just toggle microphone and listening here.
using (Speechrecognition....)
{
    while (loop for 5 seconds)
        {
            // Do something.
        }
}
Application.Exit();
// More things down here.
```

Now this piece of code can be called over and over again, which mean it will display and close the form by `Application.Exit()` when I need it to, and so far, it is doing a fantastic job beside this unexpected behavior.

Whenever I started the program and called it for the first time, it always appear and wait for fully 5 seconds due to the loop then close itself. However, if I call that part of the program again imediately right after, it might give unexpected behavior, it's a 60/40 , 60 percent chance of sitting in the loop and wait like normal then close itself, while 40 percent chance of the UI just pop on and off right after, the thread for the task is still running until application exit though, but I noticed the appearance of the UI icon on the taskbar in my second monitor so I know that it started and closed, just not displaying.

However, it will only do this if I call that part of the code again imediately right after but not after a while, an evidence that I found is after the `Application.Exit()`, I noticed the debug console said:

```
The thread 0x522c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And for 15-20 seconds later:

```
The thread 0x4af8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x162c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5f4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x66a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The problem would not occur if I waited and call it after the second part appear (10/10 test) but entirely possible after the first one, I've tried `form & environment close`, `await 2 tasks`...etc to complete before moving on but these doesn't seem to be the solution either as they are conflicted with the program structure or just that `Application.Exit()` provided a better experience. Is there any other way to improve this? Thank you!

Edit: Here is the **minimal reproducible example**, it open and close immediately randomly after the first call:

In Program.cs:

```
using minimalproblem;
namespace Minimal_reporduce
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Class1.Method1();
        }
    }

}
```

And In the backend code that responsible for calling the UI:

```
using Minimal_reporduce;//project name


namespace minimalproblem {
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Method1()
        {
            while (true) { 
            // This form is just an UI onscreen label that I want to display.
            var task = Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
            // Just toggle microphone and listening here.
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endTime = startTime.AddSeconds(5);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Command");
            while (DateTime.Now <= endTime)
            {
                
            }
            Application.Exit();
            }
        
        }
    }
    }
```

Additional question: I've read somewhere that it might be bad to just call and destroy the UI multiple time within the program life cycle, is it the case for this one and I'm doing it wrong?

Edit2: Just to add more information to the problem, I can almost guarantee that the threads is somewhat related to it behavior, because it doesn't always take that long to exit that many threads as listed, and sometime all threads was displayed almost right after the execution of Application.exit(), and if I call it then, the display will work!

Comment: Those threads may be totally unrelated to the problem. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you for letting me know, just updated the question with reproducible example

Comment: I can hardly believe that Class2 is necessary. What is `Form1`? Can we replace this by `new Form()`?

Comment: Hi @ThomasWeller, I'm mimicking the structure that I have in my code to give the best demonstration that I can. Form1 is just the default form file that visual studio gave me and yes, it could be replace by new Form(), still give the same result though

Comment: for better demonstration, I could try to upload a video of how this happen as well, but I've tried them on 2 machines and seem to have the result. Should just start the program and wait for 4,5 loop time and you should see it occur

Comment: Voting to repoen, because code has been provided.

Comment: If I am following the code you posted, it starts a speech recognition block that should run for 5 seconds and then close. Please clarify: **1** You want an app exe that you can call to listen for 5 seconds and then exits. _or_ **2** The speech recognition block is _inside another app_ that needs to turn on speech recognition for 5 seconds at a time, multiple times.

Comment: Yes, it is the 1st choice you gave that I'm working on (However the app wouldn't exit though, it would enter another loop and might run the form UI, and the speech detection again if re-triggered), everything is set up and ready beside the problem with the form. However, the problem to the flickering of the form only appear if I called it within a short time frame from the last call, and that is why I give the reproducible the while loop. Thank you!

Comment: `Application.Run` in a `Task.Run` is not going to work terribly well; that's a thread pool thread that you're coopting to run a UI loop, but without marking it as an `STAThread`. UI threads should have a main UI loop *and* be STA threads.

Comment: @StephenCleary Got it! Will work on revising my code once I done a few more research on this, this comment helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I would suggest that the speech recognition form be contained by a main form. This would allow the speech form to be re-triggered the way you mentioned. This might not be the *exact* behavior you want, but I hope it will serve as a starting point.

The [Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method should be called one time only in the program.cs entry point to start the application's main message loop.

---

[image: main form]

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

**Main Form**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonShowSpeech.Click += onClickShowSpeech;
    }

    SpeechForm _speechForm = new SpeechForm();
    private void onClickShowSpeech(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() => _speechForm.Close());
        _speechForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

---

When the button is clicked, the SpeechForm will display for 5 seconds and then close. This process can be repeated any number of times.

[image: speech flow]

**Speech Form**

```
public partial class SpeechForm : Form
{
    public SpeechForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.loadgrammar?view=netframework-4.8.1
        SRE = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SRE.SpeechRecognized += onSpeechRecognized;
        Grammar testGrammar =
          new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("testing"));
        testGrammar.Name = "Test Grammar";
        SRE.LoadGrammar(testGrammar);
        SRE.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        SRE.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        if(Visible)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Listening...";
            textBox1.Select(0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void onSpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = e.Result.Text));
    }
    SpeechRecognitionEngine SRE { get; }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to experiment with the code I used to test this answer, feel free to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/speech-recognition-listener-4-8.git) it from GitHub.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your suggestion, perhaps having a main form to just put it there would work better than the path I'm taking right now

Comment: Yes! Or at least when you say that speech form gets re-triggered it implies that "something" is doing the triggering. So, whatever that "something" is should have the speech form as one of its member objects and show it modally when needed.